# How to get variable value during IDA (Hex-Rays Decompiler) debugging?

Tags: hexrays, ios

I'm debugging a iOS App by IDA, and I need to see the value of some var like v57 below.
Through the Locals panel know the value is 0x1137D0E00LL, but I want to see the real value or class.

How to get it?
Can someone help?

Code Here:

```
v57 = sub_10AA66818();
v58 = (void *)objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue(v57);
v59 = v58;
v13 = v65;
v60 = objc_msgSend(v58, (const char *)&loc_109CB2ABC + 1, v46, v29, v65);
```

sub_10AA66818() return a OC Singleton Object and Stored in v57:

```
__int64 sub_10AA66818()
{
  if ( qword_10DCB7038 != -1 )
    dispatch_once(&qword_10DCB7038, &off_10BE41040);
  return objc_retainAutoreleaseReturnValue(qword_10DCB7030);
}
```

According to the second code box, that Singleton perform a selector to do something.

It's why I try to know what `sub_10AA66818()` return in debugging.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you mean get the value through the SDK? If not, it's showing you the numeric value of the `rax` register at that point; what other "real value" are you looking for?

Comment: @RolfRolles after analyse, sub_10A7D2818() return some string value, but it's hidden in whole app, that why I want to know real value durning debugging.

Comment: I edited my question, maybe you can get what I mean this time.@RolfRolles

Comment: sub_10AA66818() returns an int64

Comment: Why do you think that the value that it showing you is not the "real" value? Why do you think that the real value is "hidden"? Whatever value it's showing you is, in fact, the real value.

Comment: I know from header file. I saw the retuen type is a String. I want to konw the value, mead by IDAPython or some other tools. Now I can get this value, but it's memory address. I try to translate the value to the a readable value, not some hex value. @RolfRolles

Comment: thanks mate, I know the return type. @blabb

Comment: Try changing the type of `v57` to `String`, then. You might have to create the type manually in the Local Types window.

Comment: Consider `lldb` instead. You can query a lot in runtime